# Julia set and external rays for high degree

Tags: plotting, complex, polynomials

We know that the soft "Mandel dynamics" by W,Jung give us the way to draw the Julia sets and their external rays, I wonder whether there are good programs for polynomial of high degree, especially for the external ray?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This is a Q&A site about the technical software called Mathematica and the associated Wolfram Language. Are you sure you are on the right stack site?

Comment: What do you mean by "external rays"? [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Julia%20set&title=Special%3ASearch&ns0=1) says nothing about such a notion.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica does such Julia sets. For example,

```
JuliaSetPlot[z^3 - z - I, z]
```

[image]

See the documentation for more info.

Comment: Also look in https://marksmath.org/visualization/polynomial_julia_sets/